# Hide window when starting new Process C#

Tags: c#, process

Right now, I'm using this code sample to start a process through code :

```
        ProcessStartInfo processingInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processingInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processingInfo.FileName = processingFileName;
        processingInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(processingFileName);
        processingInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processingInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        Process Processing = Process.Start(processingInfo);
```

This works, but the process's windows appear on the screen, which I don't want to happen. How can I do so the window does not show up?

Also, is it possible to make it so my process does not show up in the task bar?

Comment: can you tell us exactly what application are you launching ?

Comment: why not make your program be a service process and therefore no window?

Comment: @niceman I am executing an application that I wrote on Processing (programming language), it's goal is to read info from a .txt file and send it to Serial...

Comment: ahhh I thought that you were trying to launch an external application, in that case do what Vallo suggests

Comment: @Vallo I want to have the ability to show or hide the window whenever I launch the app.

Comment: @niceman I want to have the ability to show and hide the window whenever I launch the app

Comment: okay maybe not the cleanest but you can try this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650412/hide-another-application-while-keeping-it-active

Comment: if that question didn't work I don't think you have a choice but to rewrite the application in C#, in either of Winforms or WPF you'll definitely be able to show/hide windows

Comment: Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904588/open-file-in-background-mode-using-process?rq=1